# LINQ data services "Odata" select first child from parent

Tags: c#, linq, wcf-data-services

I have an odata service that returns a parent with a child collection. Something like Order.OrderDetails. 
On the client I have tried:

```
From x in context.Order.Expand("OrderDetails") Select x.OrderDetails[0]
```

"Error translating Linq expression to URI: The method 'Select' is not supported."

```
From x in context.Order.Expand("OrderDetails") Select x.OrderDetails.FirstOrDefault()
```

"Error translating Linq expression to URI: The method 'Select' is not supported."

```
From x in context.Order Select x.OrderDetails.FirstOrDefault()
```

"Error translating Linq expression to URI: The method 'Select' is not supported."

Comment: What exactly is what you want to retrieve?

Comment: Something like Order.Status, OrderDetail(0).Pieces. Basically I need to display some properties from the Order and some properties from the first item on the order.  Or something like Person.LastName, Person.Address(0).Street...

Comment: I don't see your criteria for selecting the order in your example queries.

Comment: There is no criteria. The output is bound to a grid. I simplified the example LINQ. Let's assume I am selecting all "Persons" and their first listed address to display in a grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that aggregating (in your case FirstOrDefault) on navigation properties is not currently supported in OData except for the special cases of *all* and *any*. You either need to retrieve all of the OrderDetails (i.e. just do Expand and do a FirstOrDefault on the client) which may or may not be acceptable depending on the amount of data and your performance requirements or create a specific service operation method on the server to retrieve exactly the data you require. It seems that support for aggregation is coming in OData 4. There is a specification dated 26.02.2014 that defines aggregation in OData - http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata-data-aggregation-ext/v4.0/cs01/odata-data-aggregation-ext-v4.0-cs01.html#_Toc378326290 but I don't know if current tools support it yet.

To implement the first approach with expand you need to do something like this

```
var result = (from order in context.Orders.Expand(o=>o.OrderDetails)
              where...
              orderby...
              select order).Skip(...).Take(...) //if you need paging
              .ToList();

var actualResult = from o in result
                   select new { Order = o, FirstDetail = o.FirstOrDefault() };
```

Of course depending on your needs you may not get the first detail in this way. The point is that you execute the service query (.ToList()) before dealing with the projection.

Comment: From this article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee622463(v=vs.110).aspx I realized that I would have to pull all the records with the "expand". I used expand in my example but that does not seem to work. Once I pull the record with expand, I'm not sure how to pull the first child.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Keep in mind that the approach with specific service operation is more efficient.

Comment: While this was not exactly what I had in mind, it does work. Thanks for the help.